# AngularJS Simple Controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I was trying to run a simple Angular example using a controller. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app = "app">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/my.js"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <label for = "fname">Name:</label><input type="text" id="fname" ng-model="name"/>{{name}}
    <div class="container" ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="hero in heroes">{{hero.name}} - {{hero.city}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The Script my.js is :

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller('SimpleController',[function ($scope){
    $scope.heroes = 
    [
        {name:"Bruce Wayne", city:"Gotham"},
        {name:"Kal-El", city:"Metropolis"},
        {name:"Barry Allen", city:"Central City"},
        {name:"Kara Jor-El", city:"National City"},
        {name:"Shazam", cuty:"Fawcett City"}
    ];

}]);
```

On my local system, the *ng-model* directive works. But the controller doesn't.
I'm using 1.4.x (stable) Angular js.

I tried other question posted and did what the answers suggest, still no result.
So what am I doing wrong here?

Created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thoutead/yk8vs0ua/3/) as well. Though in the fiddle, even ng-model isn't working.

Comment: To fix the fiddle, add `ng-app="app"` attribute to your opening `<body>` tag

Comment: Updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yk8vs0ua/4/. you just need to add ng-app to body tag

Comment: @Narendar CM, thanks for fixing the fiddle guys. That was really silly of me.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't injected $scope properly into your controller. You have to put '$scope' in the array. Try this :

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller('SimpleController',['$scope', function ($scope){
// Your Stuff
}]);
```

**ADDED COMMENT**

While its perfectly okay to pass the controller function as the second argument like the other answers in the thread, I would recommend this method (where we are passing an array with dependencies and controller function) if you want to minify your code during production.

Minifiers will frequently change variable names during minification process, this method makes sure that your dependencies will still work after that.

Comment: Well, it worked flawless. Thanks :)
So the guide I was following, suggested '$scope' can be passed directly as an argument. I believe it was the case with earlier versions. Correct?

Comment: @neo.one to pass $scope directly, you pass the controller function directly as the second argument instead of array. When you pass an array as second argument, you pass arguments in this manner

Answer (score 3):

if you are using modern version of AngularJS 
I would suggest to use *ControllerAs* syntax:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="SimpleController as simpleController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="hero in simpleController.heroes">{{hero.name}} - {{hero.city}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in JS:

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller('SimpleController',function (){
    this.heroes = [
        {name:"Bruce Wayne", city:"Gotham"},
        {name:"Kal-El", city:"Metropolis"},
        {name:"Barry Allen", city:"Central City"},
        {name:"Kara Jor-El", city:"National City"},
        {name:"Shazam", cuty:"Fawcett City"}
     ];

  }]);
```

Comment: <li ng-repeat="hero in simpleController.heroes">{{hero.name}} - {{hero.city}}</li> you mean i guess

Answer (score 1):

your controller should be like:

```
 angular.module("app",[]).controller('SimpleController',function ($scope){
    $scope.heroes =  [
      {name:"Bruce Wayne", city:"Gotham"},
      {name:"Kal-El", city:"Metropolis"},
      {name:"Barry Allen", city:"Central City"},
      {name:"Kara Jor-El", city:"National City"},
      {name:"Shazam", cuty:"Fawcett City"}
    ];
});
```